# div how to make its dimensions exactly as those of the contents

Tags: css, html

How do I form a div to have the same dimensions as those of the content housed by it , and not any larger ?

The div that I currently has a larger width than that of the three divs that i have placed inside it.How can i get it to fit the inner div's size?

Here is the link to what i have now :: http://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/Fd5hQ/

HTML :

```
<div id="initial_options">
            <div class="option_button" id="option_1">
                <big>1</big> <span class="supplementary_text">text goes here</span>
            </div>
            <div class="option_button" id="option_2">
                <big>2</2></big> <span class="supplementary_text">text goes here</span>
            </div>
            <div class="option_button" id="option_3">
                <big>3</big> <span class="supplementary_text">text goes here</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#initial_options {
position:relative;
top:18%;
left:0;
z-index:10;
background-color:#eee;
}
.option_button{
width:20%;
border-radius:none;
}
#option_1{
background-color:#013adf;
}
#option_2{
background-color:#f7fe2e;
}
#option_3{
background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: you need to show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: display:inline-block;? no margins, paddings and floats

Comment: Give us something to work with. Give some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline element like `<span>` wraps around the content and more. Either you can use this or you can set the display property as `inline`.

```
div {
   display: inline;
}
```

However setting to display as `inline` will not give you any option to add top/bottom margin and padding. If you want to add that too, you should use `inline-block` as the property.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:inline-block;` without paddings, margins and floats